# NSDictionary objectForKey objectAtIndex check if is null

Tags: ios, nsdictionary

I'm trying to check if this value of my NSDictionary is null:

```
if ([[dConfiguration objectForKey:@"ButtonsMenu"] objectAtIndex:count] != [NSNull null]){
    //stuff...
}
```

But I'm getting this error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason:
>   '-[__NSCFArray objectAtIndex:]: index (5) beyond bounds (5)'

I know there is nothing there this is why I'm checking.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: It seems that count is too big (should be count -1). How did you get it?

Comment: Show the loop that surrounds that code.

Comment: One way to prevent that could be by checking the count first, then checking for the object if the count is large enough.

Comment: i was not expecting this mistake from an experienced guy . index is always one less than the length of array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's pretty simple, looks like

```
[dConfiguration objectForKey:@"ButtonsMenu"]
```

returns an NSArray or something like that, than you send it `-objectAtIndex:`, and provide index `count`.

The error tells you that your array has 5 elements and you've asked for the sixth element. I'm not sure what you want to check and why do you compare it with `NSNull`.

```
0:[first] 1:[second] 2:[third] 3:[forth] 4:[fifth]
```

Looks like you just need to check if your array has at least `count` elements in it.

```
if([[dConfiguration objectForKey:@"ButtonsMenu"] count] > count)
{
    // stuff...
}
```

But, please, note, that this is for the case when you don't have `NSNull`s in the collection (which usually is so). i.e. it just checks if your collection *has element* at index `count`. If you may have `NSNull`s in there than you should check if it has element at index and if it is not `NSNull`:

```
NSArray *buttonsMenu = [dConfiguration objectForKey:@"ButtonsMenu"];
if([buttonsMenu count] > count)
{
     id obj = [buttonsMenu objectAtIndex:count];
     if(obj != [NSNull null]) // it's ok to compare like that
     {
        // stuff...
     }
}
```

Comment: Thanks this is the best approach

Answer (score 0):

It's not so much that there's nothing there...more that even the "there" doesn't exist.

Check that your `count` is less than the number of objects in the menu before trying to evaluate anything about `objectAtIndex`, including whether it's a null object.